# swap table row using jQuery and save the new row order in database to get the same order when you leave the page

Tags: jquery, html

I have a requirement where I need to swap the table row on click of link.
 I have used the below jquery and html  code to swap the rows up and down.

My table ends up looking like this:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Swap table rows using Jquery</title>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".up,.down,.top,.bottom").click(function(){
            var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
            if ($(this).is(".up")) {
                row.insertBefore(row.prev());
            } else if ($(this).is(".down")) {
                row.insertAfter(row.next());
            } else if ($(this).is(".top")) {
                row.insertBefore($("table tr:first"));
            }else {
                row.insertAfter($("table tr:last"));
            }
         });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>
               <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
               <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
               <a href="#" class="top">Top</a>
               <a href="#" class="bottom">Bottom</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>
               <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
               <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
               <a href="#" class="top">Top</a>
               <a href="#" class="bottom">Bottom</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>
               <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
               <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
               <a href="#" class="top">Top</a>
               <a href="#" class="bottom">Bottom</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Four</td>
            <td>
               <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
               <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
               <a href="#" class="top">Top</a>
               <a href="#" class="bottom">Bottom</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Five</td>
            <td>
               <a href="#" class="up">Up</a>
               <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
               <a href="#" class="top">Top</a>
               <a href="#" class="bottom">Bottom</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

but my problem is this does not save the order of the rows once you leave the page instead of doing this every time the row is swapped, I want to save the table once, when the "Save"  button or some link  is pressed. Is this possible to implement?

Comment: Where to save ?

Comment: Thank you so much for quick respond i want to save this order of the rows into database so once you leave the page and visit again the same page  i can the same order  when i left .

Comment: And using java, php, dot not using mysql I guess ?

Comment: Yes i am using java struts 2 framework

Comment: And which database ?

Comment: Next time when you ask question, please mention all relevant details in question itself. Please once go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable suggestion i am using java with struts 2 frame work and Oracle as a database .

Comment: http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/ajax-implementation-in-struts-2-using-jquery-and-json/

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage like this instead of a database :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (localStorage.td != null) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.td)
    $('table tr td:first-child').each(function(i) {
      $(this).text(obj[i]) 
    })
  }

  $(".up,.down,.top,.bottom").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
    if ($(this).is(".up")) {
      row.insertBefore(row.prev());
    } else if ($(this).is(".down")) {
      row.insertAfter(row.next());
    } else if ($(this).is(".top")) {
      row.insertBefore($("table tr:first"));
    } else {
      row.insertAfter($("table tr:last"));
    }
  });

  $("button").click(function() {
    var obj = {};
    $('table tr td:first-child').each(function(i) {
      obj[i] = $(this).text()
    })
    localStorage.td = JSON.stringify(obj);
    console.log(localStorage.td)
  })
});
```

Se my Plunker here for a working copy: https://plnkr.co/edit/jMZ2m9NssPu9ZXPvwXGR?p=preview

If you rearrange your elements and click save then reload the page you will see that everything is like you saved it.

You can also have the save function on the fly if you rearrange the code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var obj = {}

  if (localStorage.td != null) {
    obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.td)
    $('table tr td:first-child').each(function(i) {
      $(this).text(obj[i])
    })
  }

  $(".up,.down,.top,.bottom").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
    if ($(this).is(".up")) {
      row.insertBefore(row.prev());
    } else if ($(this).is(".down")) {
      row.insertAfter(row.next());
    } else if ($(this).is(".top")) {
      row.insertBefore($("table tr:first"));
    } else {
      row.insertAfter($("table tr:last"));
    }

    $('table tr td:first-child').each(function(i) {
      obj[i] = $(this).text()
    })
    localStorage.td = JSON.stringify(obj);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but  in my case multiple users will be using the same UI and if we use local Storage like above instead of a database then all the users will be getting different different outputs when they reload the page as per their local storage .

Comment: That is correct. The your only alternative is to go with a database and do a ajax call to it.